# How to extract the location of shorter sequence based on longer sequence using Python?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, extract, regular-language

I have a file A with sequence ID and also the information of binding site location. I would like to extract the location information only without the A,T,C,G information. The shorter sequence above longer sequence shows its location and every number on the left for example in File A the value 451 is the location value on the left. I would like to get the location of short sequence on longer sequence which is start with 453 (start site) and obtain the length of shorter sequence which is size 21 and add to 453 to get the end site which is 474. Can anyone help me?

**File A.txt**

```
chr1:152806601-152807450

        TTCAGCACCATGGACAGCGCC          
451  GGCTTCAGCACCACGGACAGCGCCCCACCCGCGGCCCTCCCCCCGGCGGCGCGCTCCAGCCGGTGTAGGCGAGGC

            TTCAGCACCATGGACAGCGCC            
751  AGAGCCCCCCGGGACTGCAGAGAGCACCTGGGAGGCTGGACTGGGAACGAGACATACTCGAAGGAGTAAGTGAAG


chr10:125364276-125364825

                       TTCAGCACCATGGACAGCGCC
301  CAGTAATGTGGGGTTGTGGTCAGCACCATGGACAGCTCCCCTGTTGCTTCATATTGAGGAATAGGAAAGCGCCGC

        TTCAGCACCATGGACAGCGCC
376  TATCTCCGGATCCTGGCTAGCTCCAGCCACTGCAGGTAACTGTCTTGAATGGGCTTAGAAACATGGTGATGTCTG
```

**Desired output**

```
chr1:152806601-152807450 453 474
chr1:152806601-152807450 757 778
chr10:125364276-125364825 318 339
chr10:125364276-125364825 378 399
```

**Example code**

```
import re
with open("A.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()


label_ptrn = re.compile("")   # insert regular expression sequence ID
line_ptrn = re.compile("")    # insert regular expression start site
inner_ptrn = re.compile("")   # insert regular expression end site

all_matches = []
for line in lines:
    m = label_ptrn.match(line)
    if m:
        label = m.groupdict().get("label")
        continue
    m = line_ptrn.match(line)
    if m:
        start = m.groupdict().get("start_value")
        sequence = m.groupdict().get("sequence")
        mi = inner_ptrn.search(sequence)
        if not mi:
            continue
        span = mi.span()
        all_matches.append((label, int(start)+span[0], int(start)+span[1]))

with open("A_ouput.bed", "w+b") as f:
    for m in all_matches:
        f.write('%s\t%i\t%i\n' % m)
```

Comment: ```Can anyone help me?``` isn't very specific.  What is the problem you are having?

Comment: Are your start values off by one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks to me that the start position of your desired output is off by one.

```
        TTCAGCACCATGGACAGCGCC          
451  GGCTTCAGCACCACGGACAGCGCCCCACCCGCGGCCCTCCCCCCGGCGGCGCGCTCCAGCCGGTGTAGGCGAGGC
```

The first `T` in the shorter sequence looks like it is above the fourth character of the longer sequence.  If the first character of the longer sequence is at position 451 that would make the first character of the shorter sequence at position 454.

If the file structure is *constant* here is a non-regex solution.

```
result = []
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('chr'):
            label = line.strip()
        elif line[0] == ' ':
            # short sequence
            length = len(line.strip())
            # find the index of the beginning of the short sequence
            for i, c in enumerate(line):
                if c.isalpha():
                    short_index = i
                    break
        elif line[0].isdigit():
            # long sequence
            n = line.split(' ')[0]
            # or
            # n = line[:line.index(' ')]
            # find the index of the beginning of the long sequence
            for i, c in enumerate(line):
                if c.isalpha():
                    long_index = i
                    break
            start = int(n) + short_index - long_index
            # start -= 1
            end = start + length
            result.append('{} {} {}'.format(label, start, end))
            offset, n, start, length = 0, 0, 0, 0
```

result

```
['chr1:152806601-152807450 454 475',
 'chr1:152806601-152807450 758 779',
 'chr10:125364276-125364825 319 340',
 'chr10:125364276-125364825 379 400']
```

If I have misinterpreted your example data, uncomment the `start -= 1`.